# How to change Root View to Navigation Controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I created a Single View application with a view controller that allows you to enter homework assignment data.  I now am trying to add onto this app by creating a navigation controller.  I want the First Screen to be a Table View, that switches to the homework assignment screen when you click the "Add" arrow.

I've created the Navigation controller onto the Table view, and connected the Add button to the Assignment View Controller, but when I start the app, it still opens up to the Homework Assignment screen.

Can anyone provide a simple way to change the startup screen to my TableView?

EDIT: I am using storyboard.  I havent added/edited any new code anywhere for the Table view/ Navigation controller/AppDelegate, I just dragged and connected with storyBoard, I just need to app to startup on the table View instead of the Homework assignment View Controller.

Comment: What construction (XIB / storyboard)? Did you edit the app delegate? Show some code + configuration details.

Comment: @Wain Added that to the question

Comment: Did you change the initial view controller setting in the storyboard then? It sounds like you didn't.

Comment: Thats what im trying to figure out how to do, this is my first time using navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, select the view controller that should be the initial one. Go to the utilities view (on the right). Open the attributes inspector. Tick the `Is Initial View Controller` checkbox.